# Concat string with a Query with DateTime String

Tags: c#, .net, string, model-view-controller, informix

I am unable to Add CurrentSystemTime to my Query manually. The Query is stored in a string variable. But the concationation part is giving error:

**The Query is:**

```
string myQuery= @"SELECT MAX(ASD.eventDateTime) AS second, R.resourceID,R.resourceLoginID,ASD.agentID
                  FROM AgentStateDetail AS ASD INNER JOIN 
                  Resource AS R ON ASD.agentID = R.ResourceID WHERE ASD.eventDateTime >='" + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss") + "'AND ASD.eventDateTime <='2016-10-18 23:59:59' 
                  GROUP BY R.ResourceID,R.resourceLoginID,ASD.agentID"
```

> **The Problem part is**:
>
> WHERE ASD.eventDateTime >='" +
>   DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss") + "'
>
> **Error is:**
>
> Represent Text as unicode character Newline in constant.

Comment: The `model-view controller` tag is for pattern isolates "domain logic" (the application logic for the user) from the user interface (input and presentation), permitting independent development, testing and maintenance of each (separation of concerns). not for a SQL query.

Comment: You should have a look on prepared statements, because this is vulnerable to SQL Injection it would also increase performance and is state of the art.

Comment: @Andre: Actually, in this case the query is not vulnerable to SQL injection, because the formatting result of a datetime is fixed.

Comment: Okay that's maybe right here, but in general prepared statements are the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to start the second part of the string with an `@` which is why the compiler amends that the newline character is invalid:

```
string myQuery= @"SELECT MAX(ASD.eventDateTime) AS second, R.resourceID,R.resourceLoginID,ASD.agentID
                  FROM AgentStateDetail AS ASD INNER JOIN 
                  Resource AS R ON ASD.agentID = R.ResourceID WHERE ASD.eventDateTime >='" + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss") + @"'AND ASD.eventDateTime <='2016-10-18 23:59:59' 
                  GROUP BY R.ResourceID,R.resourceLoginID,ASD.agentID"
```

Comment: Does adding @ second time, still treats string as 1 string object ?

Comment: @BASEERULHASSAN You are concatenating three strings into one. For the compiler, each of these is treated individually, but the concatenation will combine them into one object, sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameterized query as below,

```
string sql = "SELECT MAX(ASD.eventDateTime) AS second, R.resourceID, R.resourceLoginID, ASD.agentID FROM AgentStateDetail AS ASD INNER JOIN Resource AS R ON ASD.agentID = R.ResourceID WHERE ASD.eventDateTime >= @dateTimeStart AND ASD.eventDateTime <= @dateTimeEnd GROUP BY R.ResourceID,R.resourceLoginID,ASD.agentID";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    var dateTimeStart = new SqlParameter("dateTimeStart", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    dateTimeStart.Value = new DateTime("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss");

    var dateTimeEnd = new SqlParameter("dateTimeEnd", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    dateTimeEnd.Value = new DateTime("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss");

    command.Parameters.Add(dateTimeStart);
    command.Parameters.Add(dateTimeEnd);
    var results = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```